# Issue with $(this).val().length in chrome - wrong value

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I use the following JQuery in chrome: `$(this).val().length`
this represents an input field.
Now in every other browser this works fine, but in Chrome it sometimes returns the wrong value.
Say I have 3 characters in an input field, yet `alert($(this).val().length);` will say 4.

Does anyone know why this occurs and a possible sollution?

edit:
some code

```
$("#fieldset1 input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')){
                if($(this).parent().children().last().attr('id') == $(this).attr("id")){
                    $(this).parent().next().find(':input').focus();
                }else{
                    $(this).next("input").focus();
                }
            }
});
```

I added the alert after the first if when I noticed this behaviour.

edit2: put it on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QyyBV/

HTML:

```
<fieldset id ="test">
  <input type="text" id="1" maxlength="5" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" id="2" maxlength="5" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" id="3" maxlength="5" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" id="4" maxlength="5" size="5"/>
  <input type="text" id="5" maxlength="5" size="5"/>
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript:

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

          $("#test input[type=text]").keydown(function(e){
            if(e.which == 8){
              if($(this).val().length == 0){
                $(this).prev().focus().val($(this).prev().val());
              }
            }
          });

          $("#test input[type=text]").keyup(function(e){


if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength') ){
          if($(this).parent().children().last().attr('id') == $(this).attr("id")){
            $(this).parent().next().find(':input').focus();
          }else{
            $(this).next("input").focus();
          }
        }
      });

  });
```

**Scenario**: I enter 5 4 times and then 5 once more, I backspace untill the 4th field is also empty. Sometimes (but not always) when I enter 4 5's again I jump despite that it should jump at 5 5's.
But this doesn't always happen. Sometimes I need to do it again to see this issue in Chrome.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is somewhere else in the code, and since you didn't tell us anything about the rest of the code, there is no way to know.

Comment: Tster, the code works fine in Safari, IE and FF so I doubt it to be honest.

Comment: You shouldn't have the same ID on two elements.

Comment: @jack, I use .val() and .length in chrome a lot, so I doubt that it is broken to be honest ;)

Comment: You posted the wrong part of the code.   We need to see the context that it's being called in, not what happens after you call it!

Comment: Will, I don't have the same id on two elements. I really am checking if the current element is the last element in the current section and if so go up a fieldset and selecting the first input field in the next fieldset.

Comment: @Tsar, updated it. And I'm not saying it's Chrome's fault per se. I'm new at JQuery so I might have made a stupid mistake. I am just remarking that Chrome is the only browser that I have this issue with.

Comment: @jack: Your lasted posted code has a syntax error (should end with `});`, not just `};`). Is that just a side-effect of copy-and-paste, or...?

Comment: @jack: I posted the jsFiddle code into the question. It's totally fine (quite handy, in fact) to provide links to live examples off-site, but *also* quote the code in the actual question (or answer) itself. StackOverflow is meant to be stand-alone, and external links can rot (get deleted, get moved, etc.). I also updated my answer once again. I can't replicate what you're seeing, but I've rejigged things in a way I think is useful, who knows, maybe it does the trick. Have to disappear, good luck with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update 4**:

I can't replicate the problem using Chrome (for Linux) with your fiddle.

But I noticed you're using `keydown` for one aspect of the masked edit, but `keyup` for another aspect of it. Barring a really good reason for using `keyup` instead of `keydown`, I'd use `keydown` for both — not least because then key repeat works properly with the masked edit you're creating (e.g., if I push down '5' and hold it, I switch from field to field as I expect, instead of stopping at the end of the first field).

[Here's my slightly-edited version](http://jsfiddle.net/QyyBV/6/) using `keydown`. Seems to work fine (but then, your original didn't show the problem for me either, could be OS-specific):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#test input[type=text]").keydown(function(e){
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val(),
            $prev,
            $parent;

        if(e.which == 8){
            if(val.length == 0){
                $prev = $this.prev();
                $prev.focus().val($prev.val());
            }
        }
        else if(val.length == $this.attr('maxlength') ){
            $parent = $this.parent();
            if($parent.children().last().attr('id') == $this.attr("id")){
                $parent.next().find(':input').focus();
            }else{
                $this.next("input").focus();
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Who knows, perhaps that works around the weird issue you're seeing.

**Off-topic 1**:

I didn't do it above, but since `next()` will return an empty jQuery object if there is no match for the selector, you can replace

```
if($parent.children().last().attr('id') == $this.attr("id")){
    $parent.next().find(':input').focus();
}else{
    $this.next("input").focus();
}
```

with

```
$next = $this.next("input");
if($next.length == 0) {
    $next = $parent.next().find(':input:first');
}
$next.focus();
```

...(declaring `$next` with a `var` up top, of course). That avoids the need for `$parent.children().last().attr('id') == $this.attr("id")`, which is more work than necessary. And you can add equivalent functionality to the backspace:

```
if(val.length == 0){
    $prev = $this.prev();
    if($prev.length == 0) {
        $prev = $this.parent().prev().find(':input:last');
    }
    $prev.focus().val($prev.val());
}
```

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/QyyBV/7/). FWIW.

---

**Off-topic 2**: The IDs you've given the fields in your example (`1`, `2`, etc.), while valid *HTML* IDs, are [invalid for use with CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier). IDs in CSS cannot start with a digit (or a few other things, see the link for details). I mention this because we use CSS selectors so frequently in jQuery...

---

**Off-topic 3**: Repeatedly calling `$(this)` makes your browser work harder than it has to. Each time you do it, jQuery ends up doing two function calls and a memory allocation. That may not be an issue, but there's rarely a reason not to cache the result in a local variable, e.g. `var $this = $(this);`.

---

---

**Previous updates of answer**:

---

**Update 3**:

You mentioned it happening occasionally, and you mentioned backspace, but the quoted code doesn't do anything with backspaces. So really, a pared-down, self-contained, functional example will be key to finding this. Sounds like a browser difference in the order of events vs. focus (since you're modifying focus), but...

**Update 2**:

Re your comment that it's a `keyup` handler, I'm still not seeing that behavior:

```
$('#theField').keyup(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    display("Field is at maximum, length = " +
            $(this).val().length);
  }
  else {
    display("Field is not at maximum, length = " +
            $(this).val().length);
  }
});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ugehu4/4)

Note that your latest posted code *(as of this writing)* has a syntax error (should end with `});`, not just `};`), but I'm guessing that's a side-effect of copy-and-paste.

Recommend paring your code down to the bare minimum, posting it to [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar, and we can help you find the problem.

---

**Update 1**:

My guess (*more context would help! what event handler is that in?*) is you're doing this in a `keypress` handler. As of the `keypress` event, the character hasn't (yet) been added to the field. [Live example](http://jsbin.com/ugehu4/2):

```
$('#theField').keypress(function() {
  if ($(this).val().length == $(this).attr("maxlength")) {
    display("Field is at maximum, length = " +
            $(this).val().length);
  }
  else {
    display("Field is not at maximum, length = " +
            $(this).val().length);
  }
});

function display(msg) {
  $('<p/>').html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

As far as I know, this is reliable behavior across browsers, though, so if you're really seeing in only on Chrome, perhaps you're using another event I don't have much experience with. For instance, the above is fine in Firefox.

In any case, if the problem is that the event happens too early for what you're trying to do, you can easily defer it:

```
$('#theField').keypress(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if ($this.val().length == $this.attr("maxlength")) {
      display("Field is at maximum, length = " +
              $this.val().length);
    }
    else {
      display("Field is not at maximum, length = " +
              $this.val().length);
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/ugehu4/3)

---

**Original answer**:

I suspect that there really are four characters in the field. Certainly it works as expected, in Chrome, with [this live example](http://jsbin.com/ugehu4):

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type='text' id='theField' value='123'>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
display('Length is ' + $('#theField').val().length);

function display(msg) {
  $('<p/>').html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that TJCrowder, I selected a bit too little. I am using a keyup event.

Comment: @jack: Updated the answer, just not seeing that behavior in Chrome.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That's the problem it isn't consistent. It happens every now and then when I go from a next input field to a previous one through pressing backspace so that the previous field is empty and then input 4 characters yet it is marked as 5. I'll see if I can put it on one of those two.

Comment: @jack: Sorry, just noticed you're mucking about with focus. That's probably the issue.

Comment: @jack: You mentioned backspace, but the quoted code doesn't do anything with that. So really, a pared-down, self-contained, functional example will be key to finding this. Sounds like a browser difference in the order of events vs. focus, but...

Comment: Weird that you're not seeing it while I see it on my laptop. It would surprise me if it's OS based. I switched keyup to keydown and the issue persists so that's weird. And thank you for the suggestions, I'll incorporate them.

Comment: @jack: Wouldn't surprise me at all if focus-related edge cases varied by platform. Were you able to replicate the issue with my actual fiddles? (E.g., not just with your own edited version of the code?)

Comment: Weird, not seeing it in your fiddle while I did the same thing. I also noticed that it wasn't jumping to the next field immediatly so I guess that's why I went for the keyup (I wrote the jquery a bit ago). But I can't just do maxlength -1 since that will change focus before setting the value. So that might get a bit messier to work around that.

Comment: @jack: When I try my fiddle, it jumps from one field to the next when the field becomes full, and jumps back if you hit backspace in an empty field. Seems like what you want, provided it doesn't have the weird behavior you're seeing in your original.

Comment: TJ Crowder, weird when I tried the fiddle it didn't jump. Guess I'll try a reinstall of chrome.